draggable-border-width setting in GNOME not taking effect for any application
I am running a standard GNOME Shell 46.4 on Wayland on Arch Linux. I am trying to increase the width of window borders to make it easier to drag and resize windows. There is a dconf setting org.gnome.mutter draggable-border-width which I set to the max value (64), however it doesn't seem to by taking effect for any apps or windows (including e.g. the default GNOME Console). Is there some step I'm missing or is this border width setting no longer configurable in GNOME?
